# How do I enter 1300 CSV records into a web form?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, curl

I've got a fairly extensive data entry task to perform in a PHP application. The application allows you to enter one data set at a time (first name, last name, email), click 'Go', and then uses AJAX to submit the data and blanks the form, putting your cursor back in the first input. I have a data set of 1,300 that needs to be entered using this method. It's currently in an Excel file, but of course that could just as easily be in a database, a CSV, etc.

This is by no means to exploit a site or application, it's to enter user data from an old site into a new one. I'm looking for a way to automate this entry - populate email, populate first name, populate last name, submit the form, delay a second for the response (this is running locally so it should be snappy), select a new row to insert, repeat.

Edit - I absolutely realize that JS isn't the right technology for this job, but I'm confident it can work. The ONLY reason I'm trying to use JS here is because that's the one language capable of getting this done that I'm comfortable with, and doesn't require a ton of work within the application. I can only use other technologies if it's really spelled out.. normally I'd go for the learning route, but I simply can't this time. **Sorry to be so picky!**

Comment: Why do you need jQuery to do this? MySQL does have a `LOAD DATA INFILE` or this can be done fairly easily with PHP also.

Comment: Why don't you parse the csv file with php and insert it into the database that way? or if its in a database just export it as a sql file and then import it into the new site?

Comment: The reason I need to go through the form is purely to save time. The application manipulates that data a lot before it hits the database, and at that point it makes a lot of relationships across tables that will be time consuming to replicate using a new PHP script. Should have mentioned that, but in this case automating entry through the form is absolutely the ideal way to get it done, if possible. Edit - the reason I tagged jQuery is just because it's likely there's a plugin out there that helps with this sort of thing, but I don't know if it.

Comment: I don't see why you can't do any data manipulation if the file is imported in PHP. I would even go so far as to state that this would be a *much* quicker solution as opposed to creating a sort of submission bot?

Comment: Maybe that's a better solution, but I haven't totally grasped it - can you explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: If its a csv file you can explore `fgetcsv()` or `str_getcsv()` (at the string level). If its an Excel file you could export it as xml and iterate through it using something like `SimpleXML`.

Comment: How do I submit this though the form, though? My issue is, in my case, digging into the code that makes up this application is more daunting than a bit of JavaScript, regardless of how low tech that may be, it's only a one time process.

Comment: It’s probably easier to do this as a little command line script with `curl`. My curl-fu isn’t that strong though, so unless yours is, I guess that’s not much help.

Comment: Basically, you need each bit of data in the CSV file to get url-encoded. Then, for each line in the encoded file, you need to `curl` the URL of the form, using the `-d` option to send the encoded data with the `curl` request. (You’d be making `curl` do the same thing that the web page form does.)

Comment: My curl-fu is non-existant! These alternatives seem very much legit, but I don't know how to use curl at this point and time is very much a factor in this case. The reason I'm looking at JS is because I'm familiar with it and can troubleshoot it instead of trying to dive into something I've never used before or digging into the application and modifying it or replicating its functionality. At this point it seems like there are many better options for somebody who can afford the time investment to learn something new, but I'm really looking for a JS-based solution. Your input is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I worked through this one on my own.. I appreciate all of your input, but I really needed to get this done with JS, as I explained. I'm always very adventurous, but not when I absolutely cannot spend more time than necessary on it (which is rare). The solution isn't complicated:

First I got the data into a MySQL table using LOAD DATA in phpMyAdmin. Trivial. Next, I wrote just a little bit of PHP for the JS to send AJAX requests to.

```
getUser( $_POST['uid'] );

function getUser( $uid ){
    $usr = "********";
    $pwd = "********";
    $db = "import_users";
    $host = "localhost";

    $cid = mysql_connect($host,$usr,$pwd);
    if (!$cid) { echo("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "\n"); }

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $uid";
    $retid = mysql_db_query($db, $SQL, $cid);
    if(!$retid){
        echo( "error: " . mysql_error());
    } else{
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($retid)) { 
            $user = array(
                'email' => $row["email"],
                'firstname' => $row["firstname"],
                'lastname' => $row["lastname"],
                'username' => $row["username"],
             );
            echo json_encode($user);
        }
    }
}
```

This PHP does not need to be clean, does not need to sanitize, does not need to be optimized, etc - this is happening ONE TIME, and locally.

Next, the JavaScript:

```
function incrementUser(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/path-to-php-file/ajax.php",
        data: "uid="+i,
        success: function(msg){
            console.log( "Completed: " + JSON.parse(msg) );
            var user = JSON.parse(msg);
            jQuery('#email').val(user.email);
            //jQuery('#user_login').val(user.username);
            jQuery('#first_name').val(user.firstname);
            jQuery('#last_name').val(user.lastname);
            jQuery('#user_info_form').submit();
        }
     });
    if( i > 1463 ){
        clearTimeout( time );
    } else{
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

Again - could be better executed, but it does not matter because this is a one time process. This worked perfectly, and the increment time could probably be even shorter, requiring less time to complete the process.

Thanks again for the input, probably a lot of help for somebody who either has a grasp on these other technologies or some time to play with them. Doesn't go unappreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think that making a script fill the form and submit it is complicated. The easiest way would be to submit data as the browser does when you press the "submit" button (probably via a POST request).

You said that you would like to do it only in JavaScript. You can use the jQuery ajax features (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to prepare and send queries.

To prepare the query, you have to use the same parameter names as the form (name attribute of the  elements).

The problem is how to use your CSV file from JavaScript. As JavaScript cannot access your file system, you have to use exotic solutions like pasting the CSV text in a textarea. With this method, your javascript can access the CSV data, parse it and prepare requests. Then you can use the ajax functions to send the queries.

On the other hand, you could easily do a small Python script to do this using the urllib module. I think that it would be faster and easier than using JavaScript.

In both cases, the server will act the same as if the request was sent using the "submit" button.

So the steps for your script (any language):

1. Get the CSV data
2. Parse the data and prepare a request for each line
3. Send the HTTP requests

Comment: Sorry, read this right after posting my answer - that was the right approach for sure, using an ajax call to get records one after the other - definitely worthwhile to get the CSV into a database to make that process easier. The form interaction I had been over thinking and was also pretty trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm not beign really of help, but if you must pass through the presentation layer to do work with your model, then you have a big problem with the design of your application.

Complaints aside, I'd rather go with a simple script in PHP or Python, than any JS. Using `curl` function you can send POST requests to the server with the data parsed from the CSV.

Comment: it is supposed to be their own site. to use curl on it would be nonsense

Answer (score 0):

To replicate the request the browser makes. Use a http sniffer like fiddler or paros proxy. Once you see what data the browser sends it should be fairly easy to replicate this behaviour.

An alternative solution is to script the browser with watir. Watir is made to unit test web apps, but can handle this problem fairly easy as well.

Comment: it is supposed to be their own site. to use curl on it would be nonsense. why such a mainstream answer? Did you bother to read comments at least?

Comment: Whats with the mentality that an answer has to be almost ready to copy paste and compile. I've provided a direction for the op to go look further info. I mentioned fiddler because I got the feeling that he may not be completely aware what's going on on the wire, and upon realising this it may be trivial to do with curl or another tool.